# why my controller throw an Error

Tags: angularjs

Below I have a simple form with a controller and service. Why is there an error thrown when I mention `['angucomplete-alt']`

**Html**

```
<div ng-controller="Hell">
    <input type="button" ng-click="Hello()" value="Save" />
</div>
```

**MyApp.Js**

```
var aap = angular.module('MyApp', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination','angucomplete-alt'])
aap.controller('myhmectrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.msg = "Hello Angular....";

})
```

**Conroller.Js**

```
(function () {

    angular.module('MyApp', ['angucomplete-alt'])
             .controller('Hell', function ($scope, Myservices) {

    $scope.Hello = function () {
        alert('ok ctrls');
        var xx = Myservices.GetSer();
    }
});
})
```

**Service.Js**

```
(function () {
    angular.module('MyApp', ['angucomplete-alt'])

   .service('Myservices', function ($http) {

       this.GetSer = function () {
           alert('pk Servicess....')
       }
   })
})
```

Comment: Could you add the error message you get?

Comment: Remove dependency array from Controller.js and Service.js when you need the module. Dependency injection in module is required only when the module is defined. after that just do `angular.module('MyApp')` to get the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In controller if you are passing the dependencies it will create a new module and  instantiate again, Remove the dependency

It shoule be

```
angular.module('MyApp').controller('Hell', function ($scope, Myservices) {
}
```

Comment: i have added in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didn't include js file for angucomplete-alt ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove dependency array when you are accessing your module. Modify your files as belows:

**Controller.js**

```
(function () {

    angular.module('MyApp')
             .controller('Hell', function ($scope, Myservices) {

    $scope.Hello = function () {
        alert('ok ctrls');
        var xx = Myservices.GetSer();
    }
});
})
```

**Service.js**

```
(function () {
    angular.module('MyApp')

   .service('Myservices', function ($http) {

       this.GetSer = function () {
           alert('pk Servicess....')
       }
   })
})
```